# cni0 already has an ip address

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I've got a k8s (on-premise) cluster with 1 master and 3 workers, all ubuntu, latest LTS version.

2 workers are running fine, but pods getting scheduled to one stay in the ContainerCreating state with the error.

> Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed
> to set up sandbox container "1234" network for pod
> "clean-updater-hxknv": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod
> "clean-updater-hxknv_default" network: failed to set bridge addr:
> "cni0" already has an IP address different from 10.244.6.1/24

cni0 has an ip of:

cni0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
inet 10.244.3.1/24 brd 10.244.3.255 scope global cni0

I've tried kubeadm reset and join again on the node but it didnt help. How to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this happen to me when my flannel and cni0 inet addresses were out of sync. Bringing down the cni0 bridge made it resync for me:

```
ifconfig cni0 down
brctl delbr cni0
```

Or if that doesn't work:

```
sudo ip link delete cni0 type bridge
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: actually had this again on another cluster a few weeks ago. will try soon

Comment: Second option worked for me, thanks!